# Why use _.get(err, ['data', 'error', 'code']) if you could simply do err.data.error.code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

So I've been looking for an answer given to me in a nodeJS test.
**Why use _.get(err, ['data', 'error', 'code']) if you could simply do err.data.error.code?
      And can you think of a better name for err here?** 
after 3 days of searching i can't figure out an answer  ,I may need some help 
Code:

```
if (_.includes(errorCodesOnWhichToRemoveSynchronization,
    _.get(err, ['data', 'error', 'code']))) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Update

A preferred way to do this without any external library is to leverage [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

```
err?.data?.error?.code
```

---

Lodash's [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get) is failsafe. If any of the intermediate property doesn't exist, it simply returns `undefined`, instead of throwing an error.

See the demo below:

```js
var obj = {
  data: {
    
  }
};

try {
  console.log(obj.data.error.code);
} catch(e) {
  console.log('regular method throws error');
}

console.log('lodash returns', _.get(obj, ['data', 'error', 'code']));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

By the way, in your case, `['data', 'error', 'code']` can simply be `data.error.code`.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine `err.data` is undefined or an empty object. In that case, you would get an exception that js cannot read `error` from undefined. Using underscore/lodash's `get` function is a "safer" way to access it. It does not throw that exception and just returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

Optional Chaining (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```js
err?.data?.error?.code
```

Comment: Oh, cool. They've added that in to browsers now. To improve your answer, I would say to add some explanation about null-checking and explain how this operator makes life easier. Maybe also something about compatibility too. Remember that answers are better if they are complete on their own.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Lodash has few methods to access properties that are quite handy and [_.get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get) is one of them where the main idea is for you to not have to worry if the path is not valid due to a `falsy` value along the way. Not only that but it has a `defaultValue` 3rd parameter (different in lodash/fp) where you could set a default value if the path asked for is invalid:

```
_.get(object, 'a.b.c', 'foo');  // if a.b.c is falsy you would get 'foo'
```

[_.has](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#has) is another one which would return a boolean if the requested path exists or not.

[_.result](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#result) is super handy when it comes to getting a value from a path which goes trough functions. Think about knockout and observables for example where to get from `a` to `b` you would usually need to do `a().b().c().myValue` ... so with `_.result` you would do:

```
_.result(obj, 'a.b.c.myValue')
```